# Error with tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I'm new to Swift and IOS programming but I am  trying to get some data to load using a table view but I get an error that I have never seen before. Can someone please help me out. The error is showing up on the line where I am trying to pass the cell text label my array that I created. The error is "Could not find an overload for subscript that accepts the supplied arguments"
[image]

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {


    var cellContent = [1,2,3]


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }




    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return cellContent.count
    }



    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        var cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")

        cell.textLabel?.text  = cellContent[indexPath.row]
        return cell

    }
```

Comment: Your cell content values are ints. The textLabel.text field expects a string. Put quotes around your cell Content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the error is a little misleading. The actual issue here seems to be that you are trying to set an `Int` as a `String` property. You can do that like this:

```
cell.textLabel?.text  = String(cellContent[indexPath.row])
```

With this change, your code works fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

Swift is treating cellContent as an integer array. You need to either (1) use `cell.textLabel?.text  = cellContent[indexPath.row] as String` or change the array to `var cellContent = ["1","2","3"]`

Answer (score 1):

You have to use strings for text labels. This will fix your error:

```
var cellContent = ["1","2","3"];
```